# Get clean list of file sizes and names using SFTP in unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sftp

I want to fetch list of files from a server using SFTP one by one only if their size is less than 1 GB.

I am running the following command :

```
$sftp -oIdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -oPort=22 user@hostname >list.txt <<EOF
cd upload/Example
ls -l iurygify*.zip
EOF
```

This results in:

```
$cat list.txt
sftp> cd upload/Example
sftp> ls -l iurygify*.zip
-rwxrwx---    0 300096661 300026669        0 Mar 11 16:38 iurygify1.zip
-rwxrwx---    0 300096661 300026669        0 Mar 11 16:38 iurygify2.zip
```

I could then use awk to calculate get the size and filename which I can save into logs for reference and then download only those files which meet the 1 GB criteria.

Is there any simpler approach to accomplish getting this file list and size? I want to avoid the junk entires of the prompt and commands in the `list.txt` and do not want to do this via `expect` command.

We are using SSH key authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place your `sftp commands` in a *batch file* and filter the output - no need for `expect`.

```
echo 'ls -l' > t
sftp -b t -oIdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -oPort=22 user@hostname | grep -v 'sftp>' >list.txt
```

Or take it a step further and filter out the "right size" in the same step:

```
sftp -b t -oIdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa -oPort=22 user@hostname | awk '$1!~/sftp>/&&$5<1000000000' >list.txt
```

Comment: Am I the only one who solves such problems by using the underlying ssh to upload and run code?

Comment: @Joshua  Don't know, don't care? =}  I just gave the man a solution to his immediate question - feel free to offer an alternative ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `lftp` instead of `sftp` ?

```
$ lftp sftp://xxx > list.txt <<EOF
> open
> ls -l
> EOF
```

```
$ cat list.txt
drwxr-xr-x   10 ludo     users        4096 May 24  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x    8 root     root         4096 Dec 20  2018 ..
-rw-------    1 ludo     users       36653 Mar 31 19:28 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--    1 ludo     users         220 Mar 21  2014 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--    1 ludo     users         362 Aug 16  2018 .bash_profile
...
```